# IntelliJ - how to hide file types in specific folder?

Tags: intellij-idea

I developing TypeScript application using IntelliJ IDE, and I want to hide *.js files from 'app' folder **only**. I don't want to hide js files globally, since I do need to see them in other places (e.g. in node_modules folder).

Currently I have IntelliJ 2016.1.4

I was trying to add relevant path into "Settings->Editor->File Types->Ignore files and folders":

- "./app/*.js"
- "/app/*.js"
- "app/*.js"

-> nothing seems to work

If I trying to hide 'app' or '*.js' - it does works.

So - is there any support for hiding specific file type in specific folder?

Comment: Are you using source control, for example do you have a `.gitignore` file?

Comment: ps. Is `Illidan` the blizzard character from WoW / HS or your real name?

Answer (score 6):

The `File Types` exclusion option does not support paths. However, the following, I believe, comes close to what you wish:

---

#### Step 1 : Create a custom scope

This custom scope will exclude `app/*.js` like so:

[image]

Pattern is : `!file:*/app/*.js`
(Notice from the snapshot that this pattern excludes `app` but not `app2`)

---

#### Step 2 : Configure Project view to use this custom scope

Click here and select the scope you create earlier:

[image]

Your Project view should now change from:

[image]

to:

[image]

Comment: Hi, appreciate your effort, but unfortunately it doesn't works for me - js files are not get hidden.

Answer (score 3):

Go to: File > Settings > Editor > File Types

at the bottom you can find [Ignore files and Folders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C4VO5.png), that is a list of extensions that you don't want to see in the project scope.

For example *.c;

Answer (score 0):

Preferences -> Directories

Mark the folders you want to Exclude as Excluded.